# Problema con las familias o grupos de los parámetros al llegar a mi API

Tags: javascript, api, swagger

Tengo que llamar a estos parámetros que llegan desde Signaturit hasta mi API. El problema es que están agrupados en una especie de grupos o familias. Estoy usando Swagger para desarrollar la API.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no puedo llamarlo de forma normal porque recibo este error "ReferenceError: created_at is not defined". El error realmente es normal porque está claro que created_at no está definido.

Pero necesito llamar a estas querys. Signaturit no me deja cambiar la forma en la que manda las request a mi API. Adjunto código.

**Code:**

```
params: {
     'document[created_at]': req.swagger.params.document[created_at].value,
      created_at: req.swagger.params.created_at.value,
      type: req.swagger.params.type.value,
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
'document[created_at]': req.swagger.params["document[created_at]"].value,
```

Así puedes llamar a este tipo de parámetros.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).